# Moodle: Visitors get automatically connected anonymously, how to prevent that?

Tags: moodle

I had Moodle 3.11 i upgraded to 4.2 following the procedure from the docs. But after the upgrade, (i also moved it to a new VM) i notice that when ever I go to the platform, on the top right corner it shows that i'm connected anonnymously, next to the login button. I searched through the internet, the docs, checked my settings, but couldn't fix it .

I don't want anonymous acces, at all, i want that whenever anyone lands on my platform, that they directly face the login page, and have no access to anything at all unless they log in. I already disabled the anonymous connection button as many articles suggested but it doesn't solve the issue.

EDIT:

I've already done the following actions, but it did litterally nothing that can be seen. so the issue remains:

At "Security > Site security settings" `/admin/settings.php?section=sitepolicies`, enable the `forcelogin` option.

At "Security > Authentication > Manage" `/admin/settings.php?section=manageauths` (below the plugin list), set the `guestloginbutton` option to "Hide".

At "Users > Permissions > User policies" `/admin/settings.php?section=userpolicies`, disable the `autologinguests` option

Comment: If you're referring to "Login as Guest", have a look at [this post](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=29092). It contains some some advice that you haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. At "Security > Site security settings" `/admin/settings.php?section=sitepolicies`, enable the `forcelogin` option.
2. At "Security > Authentication > Manage" `/admin/settings.php?section=manageauths` (below the plugin list), set the `guestloginbutton` option to "Hide".
3. At "Users > Permissions > User policies" `/admin/settings.php?section=userpolicies`, disable the `autologinguests` option and make sure the other settings are correct (most of them should be set to their default value).

After you are done with these settings you have to clear the browser's cache or try with another one to see the changes take effect.

Deploying Moodle from Git would allow easier and therefore more frequent upgrades, without having to jump many versions at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, sorry i didn't clearly mentionned it in my post, but i already did all you said from 1 to 3. but the problem remains.

Comment: This actually solved the problem, but i wasted so much time simply because the browser kept the "anonymous" session active, after trying with another browser or clearing the cache I could see the excpected behaviour taking place.  This is crazy! I wasted so much time on a trivial thing. Thank you!

Comment: @Xsmael it is encouraged to self-answer questions if you found a solution. Other users with the same problem may benefit from you answer mentioning browser cache and the guest session staying active even after changing the settings.

Comment: @Falco well,  I thought about it, but wanted to give credit to @ u1686_grawity so I just commented on his answer, he can add it up, or let me suggest an edit

Comment: You can still add your own solution as an additional answer and leave him the checkmark. - Comments can be deleted at any time - so relevant information should always be part of an answer.

Comment: @Falco alright then.  I've already suggested edits, if he accepts it, will it still be relevant that post my own answer ? if so i'll do it .

Comment: If the edits cover everything a separate answer is not needed. - If the user does not accept the edits you should write them up in a new answer.